# split list from text into nGrams in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to split a text file into a specific amount of words per list in list, probably be best to show in example.

say the text file looks like this

```
"i am having a good day today"
```

i have to write a function which looks like this

```
ngrams.makeNGrams("ngrams.txt", 2)
#so since the given variable says 2 the output should look like this:

[['i', 'am'],['am', 'having'],['having', 'a'],['a',’good’],[’good’, ’day’],[’day’,’today’]]
```

if the function looked like this

```
ngrams.makeNGrams("ngrams.txt", 3)

#it should give out:

[[’i’,’am’,’having’],[’having’,’a’,’good’],[’good’,’day’,’today’]]
```

Does anybody now how i should deal with this best ? 
thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, and this looks like homework. Show us what you've tried:  See [Asking about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define:

```
def ngrams(text, n):
    words = text.split()
    return [ words[i:i+n] for i in range(len(words)-n+1) ]
```

And use:

```
s = "i am having a good day today"
ngrams(s, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
def ngrams(words, n):
    return zip(*(words[i:] for i in range(n)))
```

Usage:

```
>>> words = "i am having a good day today".split()
>>> list(ngrams(words, 2))
[('i', 'am'), ('am', 'having'), ('having', 'a'), ('a', 'good'), ('good', 'day'), ('day', 'today')]
>>> list(ngrams(words, 3))
[('i', 'am', 'having'), ('am', 'having', 'a'), ('having', 'a', 'good'), ('a', 'good', 'day'), ('good', 'day', 'today')]
```

The idea is to generate `n` lists from the original list, with i-th list shifted by `i`. Then simply `zip` these shifted lists together and return the result.

Visualization for `n=3`:

```
['i',      'am',     'having', 'a',    'good', 'day', 'today']  # not shifted
['am',     'having', 'a',      'good', 'day',  'today']         # shifted by 1
['having', 'a',      'good',   'day',  'today']                 # shifted by 2
```

The `zip` function stitches the element at the same indexes together until the shortest of lists is exhausted, producing the desired output.

Comment: i am getting
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not generator

Comment: Are you using Python3?
Edit -  tried with both Python2.7 and Python3.5 and it works - I edited the answer to converted the result to a list, so that it behaves the same in both.

Comment: yes, python 3.4
i skipped using the file data and used a string as an object, just like you, but i got <zip object at 0x7f9386f8d248>

Comment: Yes, in Python3 the zip object is a generator that lazily provides the results on demand, i.e. when actually needed. You can convert it to a list by using `list(your_zip_object)` (I updated my answer as well).

Comment: Thanks a lot Plamut, have a Wonderful Day !

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more pythonic way of doing this. It is not a function (but it should be easy to adapt) but a program. I think it follows your specification:

```
import sys

num = int(sys.argv[1])

cad = "i am having a good day today"

listCad =  cad.split(" ")

listOfLists = []
i = 0
while i <= len(listCad) - num:
   listOfLists.append(listCad[i:i+num])
   i = i + (num - 1)

print listOfLists
```